# angular2/4 Observable subscription

Tags: angular

Im trying to make a api call to my server database, but its not currenty working.

I have the following error:

[image]

```
    Type 'Subscription' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Comment[]>'.
  Property '_isScalar' is missing in type 'Subscription'.
```

What im i doing wrong and why?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, RequestOptions, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Comment } from './models/comment'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class CoreService {

  constructor(private http: Http, private URLSearchParams : URLSearchParams) { }

  options = [];
  result = [];

  getUserByName(name: string): Observable<Comment[]> {

    let url = "http://localhost:8080/api";


    return this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .subscribe(result => this.result = response);
  }

}
```

comment:

```
    export class Comment {
    constructor(
        public text:string
    ){}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to subscribe to `getUserByName()` inside your component.

If that's the case you should remove subscribe from your service.

You can change it with the `do()` operator to "cache" your data.

```
return this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => response.json())
        .do(result => this.result = response);
```

Comment: do i need to import something, cause .do dosent exist.

Comment: @maria can you try `import 'rxjs/add/operator/do';`?

Comment: fixed, but somehow No provider for URLSearchParams!